# I Don't Want Null Value When I Count The Name From My Table SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by, union

```
UserName           |         Person1   |     Person2    |     Person3


Kapil              |         Null      |       Null     |     Dks


Kapil              |         Dks       |       AA       |     Null

Kapil              |         SKS       |       AA       |     Dks
```

---

Desire Output :

```
User_Name   Person    Count

Kapil       Dks       3

Kapil       SKS       1

Kapil       AA        2

Kapil       Null      0
```

I Don't Want Count Of Null Value in My Output. Can Anyone Help me???

Comment: What've you tried? Please add your code.

Answer (score 1):

To get the data you want, you need to unpivot the data.  Here is an easy way using `union all`:

```
select user_name, person, count(person)
from (select user_name, person1 as person from table t union all
      select user_name, person2 as person from table t union all
      select user_name, person3 as person from table t
     ) t
group by user_name, person;
```

If you don't want the *row* at all, use `where`:

```
select user_name, person, count(*)
from (select user_name, person1 as person from table t union all
      select user_name, person2 as person from table t union all
      select user_name, person3 as person from table t
     ) t
where person is not null
group by user_name, person;
```

However, your desired output suggests that you want the row with a count of `0`.

EDIT:

To count non-blank values, here is one way:

```
select user_name, person, count(nullif(ltrim(rtrim(person)), '') )
from (select user_name, person1 as person from table t union all
      select user_name, person2 as person from table t union all
      select user_name, person3 as person from table t
     ) t
group by user_name, person;
```

A clearer way to write this is probably:

```
select user_name, person, sum(case when ltrim(rtrim(person)) > '' then 1 else 0 end)
```

Comment: Thanks Lot Gordon. I Got a Output. But Another One Problem I Found is In My Table Some Contains Blank Instead Of Null. So Now I am Getting Blank Rows Count in My Output. How Can I Avoid Such a Blank Values and Their Count?????

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT User_Name, Person, COUNT(1) AS Count
FROM (SELECT User_Name, Person1 AS Person
      FROM tableA 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT User_Name, Person2 AS Person
      FROM tableA 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT User_Name, Person3 AS Person
      FROM tableA 
     ) AS A 
WHERE Person IS NOT NULL AND Person != ''
GROUP BY User_Name, Person;
```

Comment: Thank You. I Got The Output. But Another One Problem I Found is In My Table Some Contains Blank Instead Of Null. So Now I am Getting Blank Rows Count in My Output. How Can I Avoid Such a Blank Values and Their Count in My Output?????

Comment: OMG awesome. Thanks Lot Saharsh Shah. Its Working Fine. Thanks Alot